# Where do you upload your pom.xml file to?

Tags: java, pom.xml

Do you upload it to a version control system (e.g. SVN) or a repository manager (e.g. Archiva)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pom.xml` file belongs to the project, as it the defines the project structure and dependencies. Hence, we commit it along with all source files into our VCS.

Using a modern IDE, such as e.g., *Netbeans*, adds an extra incentive. The project can be opened and built by any developer directly after checkout without any extra effort.

Basically, the *only* time we upload a pom to a system such as Archiva/Nexus, is when we perform a `mvn release`, and then it's uploaded automatically with the compiled sources.